# Laravel route not calling function of controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I have a form in a page (blade) which redirects to a route which is to call a function in a controller however it does not even go inside the function because even a simple dd(); cannot be executed. when in route, if I change to

```
Route::post('edit/profile', function(Request $request){
dd($request);
});
```

it works. I tried to change both route's function name and controller's function name to another name still doesn't recognize.

My current route

```
Route::post('edit/profile', 'Auth\LoginController@updateUser');
```

My form line

```
<form action="{{url('/edit/profile')}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

My function inside LoginController

```
public function updateUser(Request $request)
{
    //insert code here
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: no error just redirected to the same page where my form is at

Comment: Tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: yep, i tried view:clear, cache:clear, and composer dumpautoload

Comment: btw, my route is inside Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){ } because I used php artisan make:auth

Comment: my code for edit profile was working before but idk, after i implemented make:auth and route middleware stuff i guess?

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` ? and when you do `php artisan route:list --path=profile` is it listed?

Comment: i just did route:clear too just now and yes my route::post edit/profile is listed with controller and function also

Comment: Form entry are saved or not ?
Sometime validation error may redirect back.

Comment: in function, i dd($request); but doesn't even execute. coz maybe it dont see my function or idk. in form is just plain form <form action="{{url('/edit/profile')}}" method="post"> {{ csrf_field() }} then <label> then <input> and submit button </form>

Comment: What DOES it do? Does it redirect? Does it seem to reload the page?

Comment: Yes after submit of form it just reload the page

Comment: no error in console also after submit of form

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late, but did you solve the problem? I've had a simmilar issue, inside auth group a route was not working. In my case, I had to put the route after the "Route::resource". So make sure if your are making a route that has a resource tagged, add the other routes before the Route::resource. For example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
   Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
   Route::get('category/order', 'CategoryController@order')->name('categoryOrder');
});
```

This won't work. Just put the 'category/order' route before the resource route like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
   Route::get('category/order', 'CategoryController@order')->name('categoryOrder');
   Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
 });
```

This should work. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am amazed and seriously I spent many hours behind this but couldn't find the issue. I still don't understand why it works this way.