# Laravel throws 403 Error when accessed Resource default Methods but works with custom Methods

Tags: php, laravel, module, frameworks

I have created a `Resource` Route with `Main` Controller through Admin route using `artisan` command

```
Route::admin('bank-statement', function () {
     Route::resource('statement', 'Main');
     Route::get('statement/print/{account}', 'Main@printStatement');
});
```

When I try to access above route

```
example.com/3/bank-statement/statement/2/edit   \\3 is company id and 2 is account id
```

it throws `403 Access Forbidden Error`. Whilst, if I try to access

```
example.com/3/bank-statement/statement/print/2
```

it works good.

My `Main` controller is as follow

```
namespace Modules\BankStatement\Http\Controllers;

use App\Abstracts\Http\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class Main extends Controller
{
     public function edit($id)
     {
          echo 'I am about return a View';
     }
     public function create()
     {
     }
     public function store()
     {
     }
     public function update()
     {
     }
     public function show()
     {
     }
     public function destroy()
     {
     }
     public function printStatement($id)
     {
          echo 'I am about to Print';
     }
}
```

What is wrong here? All of default methods like `edit/update/create/store etc` created by artisan command are throwing 403 error while any custom method like `printStatement` created in Main controller works good. Yes, I am accessing after Logging-in.

I found a similar question here [Laravel resource 403 forbidden](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/403-when-using-resource-controller) but it doesn't solve the issue

My `route:list` shows correct configurations

[image]

Comment: run `php artisan route:list --name=bank-statement` and check if the route is properly configured and what middleware it's using. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @KasiaU I checked and it seems all good but still not working. I have updated my question with output of route:list.

Comment: and what does the `admin` middleware look like? One thing to check is that `print` route works with `account`, while failing `edit` route works with a `statement` id.

Comment: Do you have other `route` definitions that might be conflicting? You have a `show` route for the `bank-statement/statement` route but you've added `show` to the `except` method so I wouldn't expect to see it in that list.

Comment: @Ksi I tried replacing statement with account id but it doesn't make any difference either. I checked Admin middleware as well and it looks good. Also I think if there was any issue with Admin Middleware then it should have forbid me using GET as well but it causes issue with Resource route only not with GET route

Comment: There must be some code somewhere ;)
Is the code in your controller really what you pasted?

Comment: @Peppermintology Though I am trying to call `Edit` but yet I tried removing `show` from except method but still it doesn't work.

Comment: That wasn’t my point. You’ve told the resource group to not include the show method as a route but it is in your route list. So something else is going on (possibly in your routes file) which is overriding things. Might be an idea to add all your routes to the question.

Comment: @Ksi there are update/show/create/store methods in Main controller but they are empty, nothing returns or any function. Main controller has only 2 methods edit & printStatement which has some code inside rest are empty.

Comment: @Peppermintology ok. let me add all my routes to questions. Thanks for your time

Comment: I also tried removing except method completely but no use :(

Comment: I just tested and found that all of default methods like edit/update/create/store etc created by artisan command are throwing 403 error while any custom method created in Main controller works good.

Comment: @Peppermintology I just found something new and have updated my question. Please if allow yourself some time to reread.

Comment: Please add your routes file.

Comment: @Peppermintology I found the reason and solution for my question. I thought it might be interesting for you too. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is really insane to know that sometimes when you try to access `Resource` route inside `Admin Middleware` you have to put Resource route after the GET route. It was the problem I had been facing.

Not working

```
Route::admin('bank-statement', function () {
    Route::resource('statement', 'Main');
    Route::get('statement/print/{account}', 'Main@printStatement');
});
```

Working

```
Route::admin('bank-statement', function () {
    Route::get('statement/print/{account}', 'Main@printStatement');
    Route::resource('statement', 'Main');
});
```

A similar problem was faced and resolved at [Laravel route not calling function of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463915/laravel-route-not-calling-function-of-controller)

Also make sure to create `Constructor` even though if it is empty.

Comment: I suspected it was route related and feel dumb for not having spotted this myself. Glad you got it sorted though!